# Best open source speech recognition API and engine

Tags: neural-network, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, hidden-markov-models, kaldi

I am making my speech recognition project for PC(working on Windows 8) and new in this area.The project should have basic functionality like dictation with accuracy in email,notepad etc and should response to local commands of PC.

I am using sphinx4 for my speech recognition project.I want to know,is there any better open source API than cmu sphinx? I want better in context of accuracy and large vocabulary.
Is kaldi(deep neural network based) better than cmu sphinx(HMM based)?I want to know which is better for what?

what is difference between speech API and speech Engine,as a developer what i will require to develop my software?

Please help me to give a clear vision about above questions and if possible provide some speech recognition developer or researcher community link.

Comment: CMUSphinx support channel http://t.me/cmusphinx the best developer community you can find ;)

Comment: Should I switch from CMU sphinx to kaldi?